# What is release date for next long term release?

Tags: 15.04, lts

I'm getting tired of reloading new systems on my ancient laptop. I started with Mint, then went to Ubuntu 15.04. Will I be able to go directly to the next long term release (and rest a little)?

Comment: You can install now 14.04 LTS. It will be supported till 2019.

Answer (score 1):

[April 21st](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule) is the official release date for 16.04, which is an LTS release.